# Interpolate current Course value of GPS using previous Course values

Tags: gps, coordinates, interpolation

I have a set of GPS data with Lat, lon and Course. I need to interpolate current value of course, using previous values of Course. The formula I am using is not accurate in curves.In C language I was trying the implementation.
Formula I have used is : 
 Current_Course = previous_Course + ((previous_course - previous_to_previous_course)* Ratio)

where Ratio is ratio of time difference and GPS update time.

Does anyone knows a better formula to interpolate course value.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you [search our site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bgps+%2Binterpolate)?  Several questions exactly like this have appeared.

Comment: none of them matches the requirement, i think,as i need implementation in C language(doesn't know much language), and those answers takes end points and interpolate value between points.Here with 2 points or previous points ,we need next possible Course value(a bit accurate).

Comment: I agree that although several versions of this question have appeared, none of the answers are adequate to your case. But please explain how your formula--which is linear interpolation--is "not accurate in curves" and how you would determine what *is* accurate. Are you perhaps looking for a statistical solution?  A Kalman filter?  A graphics spline?